# Polygons overlapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, polygon

In our project we are using asp.net mvc 4.5 so it is quite new for os all.
I got a map with difference polygons.  If a polygon overlap another polygon then I have to adjust the first polygon so no one overlaps I can achieve this with a metode on the PolyArea object called Difference and then make the first one equal to difference but in example 3, difference dosent work so my question is how do i get the first polygon to adjust it selv to the last in example 3. im thinking that the polygon must be disassembled into two polygons but how do I achieve this.

[image: Polygon example]

Comment: This is really a Math question, not a Programming one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it dident work when i run the difference method on the DbGeometry object it comes out worng so i tryed converting the dbgeometry object to dbGeography and then it worked.
maybe it could help others some day.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the clipping difference should remove the overlapped region, though I don't know why this doesn't work in your 3rd case. I presume it's a deficiency of the clipper you're using. You should have more success with a different clipper (eg [Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/)).

Comment: The difference did the job, just not on the dbgeometry object i was working on but you were sort of right so thanks.